# Sort Listview with a Combobox

Tags: c#

What I want is to type in a textbox before I start my packet sniffer to only show me results that I want. This is what I have but it isn't working. I want this listview to just show port 3074 using a textbox does anyone know how to do this? This is a packet sniffer

[image: The textbox where I want to choose what port]

[image: This is where I just want it to show only one port not all]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/dbc30667495c5a26127f54754441e843.png))</sub>

Anyone know how I can do that?

This is what I am using

```
namespace Network.Packet.Analyzer.App.Forms.Main
{
    public partial class FrmAnalyzer : Form, IAnalyzer
    {
        public FormaAnalyzerPresenter _presenter;

        public FrmAnalyzer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _presenter = new FormaAnalyzerPresenter(this);
        }


        //callled when ListView control selection being made
        private void lstReceivedPackets_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _presenter.CreateDetailedTree();
        }

        //start button click event method
        private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _presenter.StartClicked();
        }

        //stop button click event method
        private void tbtnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _presenter.StopClicked();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _presenter.ApplicationStarted();
        }

        // clear all button click event method
        // clearing buffer,listvie control,and treeview
        private void tbtnClearAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _presenter.ClearAllClicked();
        }

        private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ApplicationClose();
        }

        private void menuAlwaysOnTop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _presenter.TopMostClicked();
        }

        #region IAnalyzer Members

        public ListView ListReceivedPackets
        {
            get { return lstReceivedPackets; }
        }

        public ListView ListOpenPorts
        {
            get
            {
                return lstOpenPorts;
            }
        }

        public ProgressBar ProgressBufferusage
        {
            get { return progressBufferUsage; }
        }

        public TreeView TreePackedDetails
        {
            get { return treePacketDetails; }
        }

        public void SetTotalPacketReceivedText(string strNumber)
        {
            if (strNumber != null)
                lblTotalPkgsReceived.Text = strNumber;
        }

        public void SetBufferUsage(string strNumber)
        {
            if (strNumber != null)
                lblBufferUsage.Text = strNumber;
        }

        public void SetReadyText(string text)
        {
            if (text != null)
                lblStripReady.Text = text;
        }

        public bool ButtonStartEnabled
        {
            get { return tbtnStar.Enabled; }
            set { tbtnStar.Enabled = value; }
        }
        public bool ButtonStopEnabled
        {
            get { return tbtnStop.Enabled; }
            set { tbtnStop.Enabled = value; }
        }

        public bool TopMostChecked
        {
            get
            {
                return topMostMenuItem.Checked;
            }
            set
            {
                topMostMenuItem.Checked = value;
            }
        }
        public bool FormShowAsTopMost
        {
            get
            {
                return this.TopMost;
            }
            set
            {
                this.TopMost = value;
            }
        }

        public void ApplicationClose()
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        public StartupInfo StartupInformation
        {
            get
            {
                return _presenter.StartupInformation;
            }
            set
            {
                _presenter.StartupInformation = value;
            }
        }

        public void ShowErrorMessage(string message)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        public void ShowWarningMessage(string message)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        public void ShowDefaultErrorMessage()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unexpected error has acquired", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        public void ShowDefaultErrorMessage(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Unexpected error has acquired. Error message: {0}", ex.Message), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        public void ShowErrorMessage(string message, Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}. Error message: {1}", message, ex.Message), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        public void Invoke(Action act)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { act(); }));
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
        #endregion
```

This is the other part: pastebin.com/rPWMJHCe

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Nothing, I wouldn't know how to go about it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I totally understand the question. It sometimes helps if you take a screen shot of what you are looking for! One thing you can try is change the display text for the combobox by overriding the "ToString" routine on an object type. You can also sort by overriding the "IComparable" routines and calling sort on the combo box. Hopefully those help some!

Comment: Do you want to sort, or do you want to filter, or both? The title of your question says "Sort", but your text "just show those results" says filterting.

Comment: elgonzo do you have someway I can contact you like skype or something? this is what I want. I have a settings in a packet sniffer to choose the port I want it to just show the results that have a specific port on like the 5th column. I really just need to finish this lol it's been all day!

Comment: @user3140279, where is your code where the items are added to the ListView (lstOpenPorts, i guess)? Please update the question accordingly.

Comment: @elgonzo it's in the pastebin link I have provided.

Comment: Okay, give me some time for the answer...

Comment: Your amazing! What's your paypal and i'll donate tomorrow!

Comment: Done, both the answer and myself. Keep the donation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, seeing your code from pastebin, i will keep my answer rather simple. My answer is most certainly not the best and not the most elegant, and you will certainly still hit a wall here and there, but making it better and easier to work with would most likely require abandoning ListView in favor of a more capable control (such as DataGridView, for example). Anyway...

For the example given below, i'll pick the ListView `ListOpenPorts`. But of course you can adapt this approach to other ListViews as well, just pay attention to keep track of where which data is stored inside the ListViewItems.

The basic idea of a filtered content display is something *ListView* doesn't really like. It is not so much the filtering itself, but the fact that all items must be somewhere when we change or switch off filtering. What makes *ListView* suck so much in this regard is that it insists to maintain the list of items internally instead of giving us the opportunity to control and swap that list easily (hence me pointing towards *DataGridView* earlier).

The approach involves maintaining another private list **_listOpenPortItems** in the class *FrmAnalyzer* which will keep all 'open port' *ListViewItems*. This is necessary so our code can access them and feed them back into the **lstOpenPorts** *ListView* whenever the filtering is switched off or changed.

```
private readonly List<ListViewItem> _listOpenPortItems = new List<ListViewItem>();
```

To always have the correct items in the *_listOpenPortItems* list requires to **not** access *ListOpenPorts.Items* directly. Instead, methods will be implemented in the class *FrmAnalyzer* which will realize equivalent functions for any function used on *ListOpenPorts.Items* before. Those methods manipulate the private list *_listOpenPortItems* and also add/remove items to/from the actual ListView control depending on the filter settings.

Also note the two properties *IsPortFilterEnabled* and *PortToFilter*, which control filtering and which i will explain a bit later.

```
public void AddOpenPortItem(ListViewItem openPortItem)
{
    _listOpenPortItems.Add(openPortItem);

    if (!IsPortFilterEnabled || PortToFilter == openPortItem.SubItems[3])
        lstOpenPorts.Items.Add(openPortItem);
}

public void RemoveOpenPortItem(ListViewItem openPortItem)
{
    _listOpenPortItems.Remove(openPortItem);

    if (!IsPortFilterEnabled || PortToFilter == openPortItem.SubItems[3])
        lstOpenPorts.Items.Remove(openPortItem);
}

//...Also implement here methods for all other functions of
//...ListOpenPorts.Items you used before (such as RemoveByKey, ContainsKey, etc...)
//...which will have to realize the equivalent function on _listOpenPortItems.
//...Any method which can potentially alter _listOpenPortItems will have to have a
//...code snippet like:
//     if (!IsPortFilterEnabled || PortToFilter == openPortItem.SubItems[3])
//         lstOpenPorts.Items.XXXXXX(openPortItem);
//
//...(where XXXXXX is the appropriate method of lstOpenPorts.Items)
```

(Note that i here assume the port number being the subitem with index 3.)

With those methods implemented, just replace all direct accesses of *ListOpenPorts.Items* with the respective method calls. For example:

```
_view.Invoke(() => _view.ListOpenPorts.Items.Remove(item));
```

would be replaced with:

```
_view.Invoke(() => _view.RemoveOpenPortItem(item));
```

This code change sound like difficult work, but it is actually not that hard and just a question of finding all usages of "ListOpenPorts"/"ListOpenPorts.Items" - a simple text search through your whole source code is the bigger part of the job.

To control the filter we will use the two properties i already mentioned: **PortToFilter**, a String property which will hold the port number to filter for; and **IsPortFilterEnabled**, a bool property denoting whether the filter is enabled or not.

Both properties are, like the methods above, implemented in the class *FrmAnalyzer*.

```
public bool IsPortFilterEnabled
{
    get { return _isPortFilterEnabled; }
    set
    {
        if (_isPortFilterEnabled != value)
        {
            _isPortFilterEnabled = value;
            RefreshOpenPortListView();
        }
    }
}
private bool _isPortFilterEnabled = false;

public string PortToFilter
{
    get { return _portToFilter ; }
    set
    {
        //
        // Note that setting PortToFilter will turn on the filter
        //
        if(!_isPortFilterEnabled || _portToFilter != value)
        {
            _portToFilter = value;
            RefreshOpenPortListView();
        }
    }

}
private string _portToFilter = "0";
```

Remark: It would be better to handle port numbers as what they are - int numbers, not strings. But since you already use strings for port numbers, i chose the string data type here, too.

You might notice the calls of method *RefreshOpenPortListView*. This is a method which updates *lstOpenPorts.Items* according to the filter settings.

```
private void RefreshOpenPortListView()
{
    //
    // Note that this method does not preserve the current selection in the List View.
    // If you need to preserve it, save the current selection here and restore it
    // at the end of this method again.
    //

    IEnumerable<ListViewItem> itemsForListView =
        (_isPortFilterEnabled) ?
            _listOpenPortItems.Where(item => PortToFilter == item.SubItems[3])
            : _listOpenPortItems;

    lstOpenPorts.BeginUpdate();

    _lstOpenPorts.Itmes.Clear();

    foreach(ListViewItem item in _itemsForListView)
        _lstOpenPorts.Add(openPortItem);

    _lstOpenPorts.EndUpdate();
}
```

(Note that i here assume the port number being the subitem with index 3.)

Finally, how do you set *IsPortFilterEnabled* and *PortToFilter*? Here one idea briefly outlined, but there a numerous different ways of how to do that:

Let a checkbox toggle the value of *IsPortFilterEnabled*. This checkbox basically enables/disables the filtered view.

Let a (numerical) textbox dump its content into *PortToFilter*. This textbox contains the port number to filter for. Note that (according to my suggested implementation) whenever the textbox transfers its content to *PortToFilter*, the filtered view is enabled and updated.

Comment: This is truly amazing but I get errors after I did everything you said, and no I will not hold the donation you honestly deserve it. I will give you $15.00 tomorrow? also do you have TeamViewer?

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort or filter?, your title says sort, but your description says "to just show those results"

If your Listview is bound to a DataTable, then you can filter or sort using the DefaultView property.

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            dtItems.DefaultView.Sort = "ID";
        else
            dtItems.DefaultView.Sort = "Name";

        MyBindMethod(dtItems);
    }
```

Or if you want to filter by ID

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtItems.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ID = '" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "'";

        MyBindMethod(dtItems);
    }
```

Comment: This don't work cause it's throwing errors everywhere.

Comment: @user3140279, what errors (give a few examples)? I hope you have not blindly copy'n'pasted OHDevs code snippet, but instead adapted it to your actual code :)

Comment: I did, what can I say! I'm new lol! I feel like such a freaking retard. I don't understand what dtitems is. Is that the listview or??

Comment: @user3140279, i see your problem. Look, OHDev gave an example(!) of how to do things. Think about it being like an illustration - it is not photoreal, but contains the essential and important information. You will have to adapt the code snippet (rather the algorithm it displays) to your source code :)

Comment: @elgonzo would you be able to help me please?

Comment: @user3140279, okay, but you will have to be more precise and put more information in your question above. Are you using Windows.Forms or WPF? (Both have a ListView). Then show your actual and real code (the method) in your question where you add those items to the ListView. Do you want to sort or do you want to filter? Based on that information, we can work forward.

Comment: @elgonzo Just added the code of the form, do you need the code of all the functions too? if so it won't let me add on here so I will pastebin it.

Comment: Ok, could you paste the code of the method that fills the Listview?